# ¿Cómo reemplazar una comilla que esté en medio de dos caracteres en php?

Tags: php, regex

Tengo un archivo de texto con múltiples **sql's**, lo que quiero es que cuando haya una comillas entre dos caracteres por ejemplo: **"C'M"**, pues quiero reemplazar esa **"'"** de forma que no afecte la cadena **"\'"**

```
preg_replace("","\'",$data);
```

No sé que patrón poner para que las encuentre, quien me pueda ayudar se lo agradezco

Comment: Hola, usa str_replace("'", "TUREEMPLAZO", $data)

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor qué sentido tiene lo que quieres hacer? Si estás tratando con datos como `O'Brian, O'Donnel` etc lo correcto no es modificar los datos, sino montar tu programa para que maneje sin problemas ese tipo de datos. Me temo que estás optando por una solución poco eficaz y peligrosa en el sentido de que modifica los datos. ¿Hay algo que justifica realmente que los datos sean modificados? ¿Por qué tienen que ser modificados, siendo que los datos reales son así?

Comment: @A.Cedano la cuestión es que cuando estoy haciendo una inserción de una cantidad de datos bastante grande por lo que tengo que hacer que las "'" no me generen problemas pensando que me cerró la cadena, osea sí tengo en la cadena `'O'Brian', 'O'Donnel'` me va a presentar un error

Comment: @FernandoTorres entiendo, pero necesito saber el patrón que diga donde hacer el reemplazo, es lo que no sé

Comment: Como sospechaba tu problema se encuentra a otro nivel. Seguro que en tu contexto no estás usando consultas preparadas para insertar los datos, pues de ser así, tal implementación sabría cómo manejar los casos como `O'Brian`. Al pasarle los datos a mano, no sólo cometes el error de modificar los datos para así forzar un funcionamiento, sino que además incurres en un grave problema de seguridad. Con consultas preparadas debería funcionar, a no ser que haya que modificar también algunas cosas a nivel de configuración de la tabla a lo BD. Te aconsejo que para estos casos vayas a la raíz del asunto

Comment: En todo caso si tu justificación hacia @A.Cedano es la que mencionas, usa al momento de insertar funciones como addslashes para escapar las comillas e insertarlas en la base de datos.

Comment: El problema es que no tengo administraciones de las tablas, no puedo modificarles nada, solamente tengo que intentar subir esos datos sin que me error, tienes una idea de cómo @A.Cedano? te agradezco.

Comment: Ya te lo dije, tu solución para este caso sería usar consultas preparadas, no pasar los datos directamente a la consulta. Cuando usas consultas preparadas, se prepara la consulta (valga la redundancia) y **los datos se pasan aparte**, así, cuando pasas un dato como `O'Donnel`, el programa lo maneja limpiamente (si tiene que escapar algún caracter lo escapa) y lo inserta sin ningún tipo de problema. Aparte de eso, blindas el código contra ataques de Inyección SQL.

Comment: Puede utilizar el metodo addslashes() que agrega un slash invertido a todos los cararcteres que casusen conflictos con el texto!

Answer (score 0):

Para iniciar no es recomendable alterar la data por ejemplo en ingles no es lo mismo "John's car" que "Johns car".
Esto además de generarte un error es una vulnerabilidad conocida como Inyección SQL, investiga un poco acerca de esto. Para estos casos lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar "Prepared Statements".

Las sentencias preparadas se ven algo asi en la sentencia/consulta pones tus parametros como "?", más adelante le asignas valor en el orden correspondiente:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tu_tabla(nombre, valor) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $nombre);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $apellido);    
$name = 'Maria';
$value = "apellido con comilla";
$stmt->execute();
```

Enlaces que pueden ayudarte:

> https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp
>   https://www.php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php
>   https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php